# C#, Getting some random numbers via Serial Port(wrong values)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, event-handling, serial-port

What im trying to do, is get string data from my MICROCONTROLLER by pushing a button on it, but what I'm getting on my c# program, is some random numbers(picture is attached). For example, I want to receive "5", but I receive "650683" instead.
 On the mk side everything is working, I checked it with Emulator.
Thanks is further.
[Random numbers picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0dOX.png)

```
  If Button_1 = 0 Then 
     Led_sent = Led_on 
     Print "5" ; 
     Bitwait Button_1 , Set 
     Led_sent = Led_off    





using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.ComponentModel;    
using System.Data;    
using System.Drawing;    
using System.Linq;     
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;     
using System.Windows.Forms;    
using System.IO.Ports;    

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         public Form1()
         {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   // Here i send a byte to MK
         {
             var dataByte = new byte[] { 0x00 };
             serialPort1.Write(dataByte, 0, 1);
         }

         private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // choosing a right com port
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = textBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

        }
        int rs;
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // Data Receive Handler
        {
            try
            {
                rs = serialPort1.ReadByte();
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(type));
            }
            catch (System.TimeoutException) { }
        }
        void type(object s,EventArgs e)              // receive data
        {
            textBox4.Text += rs.ToString(); 
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   // OPen port
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Close port
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The numbers aren't random, they are periodic.  So that is something.  As for integrating with the MICROCONTROLLER (whatever that is, there are thousands of different kinds) I doubt anyone will be able to help you without much, more information about it.

Comment: microcontroller atmega8. The thing is tht i ried send diffrent types of data, hex, decimal, byte and string. Result the same i get this numbers, yeah they are diffrent, thoght the problem is in c# code, expecting that my EventHandler is working wrong

Comment: what about "ToString" operate? I send "5" as  a string, but i dont get that number  {
            textBox4.Text += rs.ToString(); 
        }

Comment: are you supposed to send Byte value 5 or Ascii character 5 to the device?

Comment: Do you have an interface specification that you are working with?  What does it mean "I want to receive '5'"?

Comment: Yeah, im working with BASCOM AVR, it has BASIC syntex, and i wrote that when i push i button on mk, i send a "5" to my textbox, i updated my topic with this code, dunno does it help

Comment: "5" as byte value

Comment: First of all don't use ToString(), use System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[]{myByte}) instead. Second, make shure that your standart protocol sending raw data into port, and don't create a structured data packet. I think thats why in emulator he show you a normal output, because he knows how parse data from that mk. try read more than 1 byte, if there will be additional bytes it will confirm that you have a packet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two obvious issues.

### Serial ports need a lot of settings

It has been a long time since I've worked with serial ports, but as I recall there are a ton of settings that cannot be negotiated automatically, e.g. whether parity bits are used, whether stop bits are used, whether to wait for CTS signal, etc.  Check the manual and make sure you have set all of these correctly.

### Message format isn't always obvious

Just because you wrote code that says `Print 5` does not mean a five comes through the cable.  You need to know how that 5 is encoded, whether it is contained in any meta-data, whether newline or carriage return is sent, whether it is ASCII or UTF8, etc.  Again, consult the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Now, im trying to send binary "&B1010_0111". When i send, i recieve 123. I guess i need make my WFA program accept bytes. i did this, "byte A = 255; textBox4.Text += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { A });" but now i dont receive anything, pretty sure its wrong, confused how to do it write